# How to calculate Mortgage calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

I have this formula for Mortgage calculation and now i want loan amount value using with same formula.

```
Loan amount = Monthly Payment/ ((1 + Interest rate per annum/100) ^ Term of loan) * Term of loan * 12
```

For example
Interest rate per annum is : 1.09
Term of loan is : 30 years
Monthly Payment is : S$ 3,049.40

So how to get **Loan Amount**?

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I presume this is homework. In practice the amount is typically compounded monthly, so the term would be in months, and the interest rate a per month rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How?

- Substitution (you're given all the values you need to completely fill in all quantities on the right hand side of the equation).
- Simplification of RHS.
- Calculation of RHS. The loan amount (the left hand side of the equation) equals the the right hand side, and when the right-hand side is evaluated using the given values, it will give you precisely what the loan amount is equal to.

$$\text{Loan amount}\; = \dfrac{\text{Monthly Payment}}{\left(1 + \dfrac{\text{Interest rate per annum}}{100}\right)^{\large \text{(Term of loan)}}} \times \text{Term of loan} \times 12 $$

$$\text{Loan amount}\; = \dfrac{3049.40}{\left(1 + \dfrac{1.09}{100}\right)^{30}} \times 30 \times 12$$ $$= 3049.4\times (1.0109)^{-30} \times 360 \approx 792996.01$$

Comment: Hi i am not getting right answer with my formula so can you explain me with this example :)

Comment: You'll need to clarify which expressions are in the numerator, and which in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation but i am getting this result: 624153 and this is not right output. The actual result is 936000. I am referring this code check this link: http://postimg.org/image/xf335r73z/

Comment: The "calculator" you link to must be using a different formula. I repeatedly am getting 792996.0068, with the given formula and values.

Comment: As copper.hat indicates, typically, the interest rate is compounded monthly, so the term would be in months: 30 \times 12. I suspect the online calculator you are using is using a different formula.

Comment: @Amzoti Yes...I worked with what was posted. I wonder if OP checked his/her work using an online calculator (a calculator based on a more complex function that the given function).